# C# boolean are not saved when updated on Object

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

*---Post updated after to many errors found on first code---*

I have some trouble with Boolean on Object.
This is my Chunk class containing a Zone struct :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new Chunk();
    }
}

public class Chunk {
  List <Zone> zones;
  public Chunk() {
    // Create 3 elements on the List
    this.zones = new List<Zone>();
    this.zones.Add(new Zone(1));
    this.zones.Add(new Zone(2));
    this.zones.Add(new Zone(42));

    // Add coord to 2th zones
    this.zones[0].AddCoord(1);
    Console.WriteLine("Count : " + this.zones[0].coords.Count); // -> Count: 1

    // Now with bool - NOT WORKING
    this.zones[0].SetBool();
    Console.WriteLine("Bool: " + this.zones[0].isOnChunkBorder ); // -> Bool: False

    // Now with bool - WORKING
    this.zones[0] = this.zones[0].SetBoolAndReturnThis();
    Console.WriteLine("Bool: " + this.zones[0].isOnChunkBorder ); // -> Bool: True
  } 

  public struct Zone {
    public bool isOnChunkBorder;
    public List<int> coords;

    public Zone(int firstCoord) {
      this.coords = new List<int>();
      this.coords.Add(firstCoord);
      this.isOnChunkBorder = false;
    }
    public void AddCoord(int coord) {
      this.coords.Add(coord);
    }
    public void SetBool() {
      this.isOnChunkBorder = true;
    }
    public Zone SetBoolAndReturnThis() {
      this.isOnChunkBorder = true;
      return this;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know why struct boolean are not updated when I'm using a simple update, but works fine is Zone is replaced by Class or if the struct is returned ?

Comment: I didn't understand why my boolean are not updated the first try if I just do `public void SetBool() {  this.isOnChunkBorder = true; }` witout returning the object.

Comment: How could we run your code to see it ourselves? Please provide a complete runnable and syntactically correct example.

Comment: @John3136 why not, the method returns `this`.

Comment: @John3136 I create a new function who return a Zone

Comment: @Arthur edit your code to show calling the correct function. I cut and paste your code. As written it would not compile. This is why you should cut and paste actual code and not re-type. People may focus on problems that don't really exist.

Comment: After I fixed a bunch of syntactic errors there - I cannot see the behaviour you're explaining: http://ideone.com/eKZpRm That's actually the reason to provide runnable examples, not quicly made ones, since there is a chance you're oversimplifying it to the point when it becomes too different from what you actually have.

Comment: Sorry this is not the entire version of my code. it's to big to be here

Comment: You don't need to put your entire code here. Just create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. for example, you have a lot of code that references some variable named `i`, but it's not defined anywhere. You could just change it to a `0` or `1` for demonstration purposes...

Comment: @RufusL that was my goal, but made mistake. I updated my post to fix errors

Comment: You **HAVE NOT**. If I added the **MISSING** `using` directives it does not compile: `error CS0246: The type or namespace name \`Vecor2' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?` Please, provide an example that one can copy paste and run **WITHOUT ANY CHANGES** required.

Comment: I didn't try to run this, I don't know how to run C# code without an entire Unity project :( So I try to explain a problem without copy/past an entire project. Sorry for mistake, i try to update the question to find my exact problem.

Comment: hard to believe it's a question by a OP with so many points, though he may be new to C#.

Comment: "I don't know how to run C# code without an entire Unity project" --- run it here: http://ideone.com/ or here https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: @LeiYang you saw right, I do JS and I just start with C# (and I also have some problem with English)

Comment: JS is no different from C# in the debugging process: you need to provide a complete runnable example for either.

Comment: Are the nested classes intentional?

Comment: Okay everyone, thank for helping to find the problem with some tips (ex ideone.com). I figure out it's working fine with class zone, but on my code i'm using struct.. So I updated all the question. Sorry again for the bad post

Comment: And that's because structs are value types. So they are copied on assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you observe caused by the `Zone` being a struct.

Structs are [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) and are copied on assignment.

Comment: Okay, but I don't understand why it's working with List update ?

Comment: @Arthur because the new struct is created and returned to you, and then you use it.